# Swift: Maximum Double Number

Tags: swift

Is there any way to get the maximum number of type Double in Swift? The number such that `anyDoubleNumber < theNumber` will always be true.

Comment: That's obviously not possible if you pick anyDoubleNumber = theNumber.

Answer (score 10):

I have found the solution to my own question.

```
var theNumber = Double.infinity
```

Should do the work. :)

Answer (score 0):

`Double.infinity` addresses the original problem of ensuring that `anyDoubleNumber < theNumber` is always true but there is also `Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude` which is more consistent with the other numerical types (like `Int.max`).

Infinity is a fairly special case specific to floating point math.